# java.io.IOException: Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified

Tags: google-authentication, google-photos-api, google-auth-library

I am trying to authenticate a java app into the google photos api, using my own account, which doesn't support service_account as per documentation. The problem is that the file generated by the google-console for OAuth2 authentication doesn't contain a type field, that only the file generated by creating credentials for a service account will work.

I tried authenticating the web-app through `gcloud auth application-default login` with/without reading the generated file, which does contain a type/client_id/client_secret/refresh_token.

E.G.:

```
        PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
                PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                                GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                                        new FileInputStream("credentials.json")
                                )))
                        .build();
```

Any ideas that might help?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue when trying to use Google API for Calendar.
As explained [here](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141), your json file is invalid. He explains how to generate the correct json, using the "Service Account key" credential.

I don't know if this solves your problem, but it didn't for me. This type of credential requires a G Suit account, which wasn't what I was looking for. I was using the [GoogleCredentials](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/index.html?com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html) for OAuth2 authentication and in my json file, the only things it requires is **type, client_id, client_secret** and **refresh_token**.

The **type** accepts **"service_account"** (for G Suit) and **"authorized_user"** (for OAuth2).

Comment: Had the same issue, and followed the solution flow mentioned by Caio.  If you check the SA key downloaded, it does have a type entry.  Once that was added, the authentication worked without a glitch.

Comment: Where can I find type and what it is?

Comment: I had the similar issue, and applying this solved it.
I used the **type:** `authorized_user` and the set the three fields mentioned above.